# Image database with filterable tags

Tags: mysql, sql, image

I currently have over 2000 images which i need to add to a database, along with tags associated with each image, and then be able to pull the images onto a webpage depending on which tags match from a series of drop down boxes

At the moment they are in a zenphoto gallery but i'm thinking about doing this from scratch as it can't do what i need it to.

Can anyone help with where i should start? or have some examples of something similar which i could look at

any help appreciated

Comment: Are you planning on storing the images in the database itself (possible, but there are issues), or just links (probably better)?  What RDBMS are you planning on using?  Just about any of them should be able to handle that (minuscule) load, although some of them may be easier to work with.  This sounds like a simple many-to-many relationship (photos to tags).

Comment: ah yes sorry, just the links. I am fairly familiar with mySQL databases if that answers the RDBMS question?

Comment: StackOverflow users expect you to ask specific questions, rather than opening a discussion - you may want to rephrase your question! See the FAQs...

Comment: Tagging schemas: http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html
http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/06/tagsystems-performance-tests.html

Answer (score 2):

A relatively simple starting schema for tagging looks along these lines:

```
image
========
id  -- identity, autoincrement
location  -- varchar(250), or however long (url)
title  -- varchar(50)

tag
========
id  -- identity, autoincrement
name  -- varchar(50)
description  -- varchar(250)

image_tag
=========
imageId  -- fk to image.id
tagId  -- fk to tag.id
```

The tuple (`imageId`, `tagId`) should be unique.

If you're wanting to deal with internationalized tags, use the following tables instead:

```
language
==========
id  -- identity, autoincrement
ISO3  -- Standard ISO 3-character code 
language  -- Standard ISO name of the language (which may all be in english...)

tag
======
id  -- identity, autoincrement
name  -- varchar(50) - it's debatable whether tag names should be
                     - translated, or left in the originating language

internationalized_tag
=======================
tagId  -- fk reference to tag.id
languageId  -- fk reference to language.id
name  -- varchar(50) - see tag.name
description  -- varchar(250) - translated description text.
```

There's obviously more you can do here, but this should get you started.